# I have a little problem in the delete function.After i delete a certain data,the remaining 2 datas keeps their id numbers stays constants

Tags: java, crud

1. This is the code

   ```
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import java.util.ArrayList;

     public class Main{ 
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
             ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
             boolean initiated = false;
             int personID = 0; //Numbering the profiles
             int operation = 0; //User Choice
             int target = 0; //Targeted profile

             while(operation != 0|| initiated == false){
                 System.out.println("============================");
                 System.out.print("1-Add Person\n2-Edit Person\n3-Delete Person\n4-Print Report\nSelect Option: ");
                 operation = scanner.nextInt();
                 System.out.println("============================");

                 if(operation == 1){
                     personID++;
                     Add(scanner, personID, name);
                 }
                 else if(operation == 2){
                     Edit(scanner,target,name);
                 }
                 else if(operation == 3){
                     System.out.println("PROFILE DELETE");
                     Delete(scanner, target, name);
                     personID--;
                 }
                 else if(operation == 4){
                     System.out.println("Reporting Records..");
                     Report(name);
                 }else{
                     System.out.print("Input Error!");
                     return;
                 }

                 if(operation != 4){
                     Report(name);
                 }
                 initiated = true;
             }
         }
         public static void Add(Scanner scanner, int personID, ArrayList<String> name){
             System.out.println("PROFILE ADD");

             name.add(Integer.toString(personID));
             String dummyScaner = scanner.nextLine(); //DOes Nothing but makesure FName gets an input
             System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
             String input0 = scanner.nextLine();
             name.add(input0);
             System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
             String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
             name.add(input1);
             System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
             String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
             name.add(input2);
         }
         public static void Edit(Scanner scanner, int target, ArrayList<String> name){
             System.out.println("PROFILE EDIT");
             Report(name);
             System.out.print("Enter Number you want to update: ");
             int targetID = scanner.nextInt();

             target = (targetID-1)*4;

             System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
             String dummyInput = scanner.nextLine();
             String input0 = scanner.nextLine();
             name.set(target+1,input0);
             System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
             String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
             name.set(target+2,input1);
             System.out.print("Age: ");
             String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
             name.set(target+3,input2);
             System.out.println("Number "+target+" updated successfully!");
         }
         public static void Delete(Scanner scanner, int target, ArrayList<String> name){
             System.out.println("PROFILE DELETE");
             Report(name);
             System.out.print("Enter Number you want to delete: ");
             int targetID = scanner.nextInt();

             target = (targetID-1)*4;

             name.remove(target+3);
             name.remove(target+2);
             name.remove(target+1);
             name.remove(target);

             System.out.println("Number "+target+" deleted successfully!");
         }
         public static void Report(ArrayList<String> name){

             System.out.println("============================\n");
             System.out.print("No. | First Name | Last Name | Age");
             for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                 if(i%4==0){
                     System.out.println("");
                 }
                 System.out.print(name.get(i)+" | ");
             }
             System.out.println("");
         }  
     }
   ```

   //To Do List:
   //Fix: Delete Function
   // Issue: When deleting a profile, with id number, the profile ID remains constant and does not adapt to new profile count.
   // Ex: you have 3 profile and then you decided to delete 3. there will be 1 and 2 left.
   //      But if you decided to delete 2 instead, it'll show 1 and 3 instead of being 1 and 2.        This is the to do list
   [image: Output]

Comment: Why should they be consecutive if you delete an entry in the middle? You store the id together with the first name, last name and age in the list. Why do you expect these ids to change?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to create a class to represent a person,

```
public class Person {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String age;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}}
```

And use this class in your Main ArrayList,
For the id it is rather necessary to speak of index at this moment, here is the modification to make to your main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> personnes = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean initiated = false;
    int personID = 0; //Numbering the profiles
    int operation = 0; //User Choice
    int target = 0; //Targeted profile

    while(operation != 0|| initiated == false){
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.print("1-Add Person\n2-Edit Person\n3-Delete Person\n4-Print Report\nSelect Option: ");
        operation = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("============================");

        if(operation == 1){
            personID++;
            Add(scanner, personnes);
        }
        else if(operation == 2){
            Edit(scanner,target, personnes);
        }
        else if(operation == 3){
            System.out.println("PROFILE DELETE");
            Delete(scanner, target, personnes);
            personID--;
        }
        else if(operation == 4){
            System.out.println("Reporting Records..");
            Report(personnes);
        }else{
            System.out.print("Input Error!");
            return;
        }

        if(operation != 4){
            Report(personnes);
        }
        initiated = true;
    }
}
public static void Add(Scanner scanner , ArrayList<Person> name){
    System.out.println("PROFILE ADD");


    String dummyScaner = scanner.nextLine(); //DOes Nothing but makesure FName gets an input
    System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
    String input0 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
    String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
    String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
    name.add(new Person(input0, input1, input2));
}
public static void Edit(Scanner scanner, int target, ArrayList<Person> name){
    System.out.println("PROFILE EDIT");
    Report(name);
    System.out.print("Enter Number you want to update: ");
    int targetID = scanner.nextInt();

    target = (targetID-1);
    Person person = name.get(target);

    System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
    String dummyInput = scanner.nextLine();
    String input0 = scanner.nextLine();
    person.setFirstName(input0);
    System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
    String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
    person.setLastName(input1);
    System.out.print("Age: ");
    String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
    person.setAge(input2);
    System.out.println("Number "+target+" updated successfully!");
}
public static void Delete(Scanner scanner, int target, ArrayList<Person> name){
    System.out.println("PROFILE DELETE");
    Report(name);
    System.out.print("Enter Number you want to delete: ");
    int targetID = scanner.nextInt();

    target = (targetID-1);

    name.remove(target);

    System.out.println("Number "+target+" deleted successfully!");
}
public static void Report(ArrayList<Person> name){

    System.out.println("============================\n");
    System.out.println("No. | First Name | Last Name | Age");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        Person person = name.get(i);
        System.out.println((i + 1) + " | " + person.getFirstName() + " | " + person.getLastName() + " | " + person.getAge());
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```